# Unpublish node after duration

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When users purchase a product (in this case a length of publication), I would like to publish one of their nodes they choose. Now after that time, I would like that node to be unpublished. How could I configure Rules to automate this process for me? Is there a better module for this?

Comment: Should this be moved over to Drupal Answers?

Answer (score 0):

you can use rules for that, see in [Rules Group](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21377)
or script it yourself, see this [Forum Question](http://drupal.org/node/374592)